# Scala/Spark - Convert Word2vec output to Dataset[_]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, word2vec

I believe the case class type should match with DataFrame. However, I'm confused what should be my case class type for `text` column?

My code below:

```
case class vectorData(value: Array[String], vectors: Array[Float])
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val word2vec = new Word2Vec()
        .setInputCol("value").setOutputCol("vectors")
        .setVectorSize(5).setMinCount(0).setWindowSize(5)
    val dataset = spark.createDataset(data)

    val model = word2vec.fit(dataset)


    val encoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product[vectorData]
    val result = model.transform(dataset)

    result.foreach(row => println(row.get(0)))
    println("###################################")
    result.foreach(row => println(row.get(1)))


    val output  = result.as(encoder)
}
```

As shown, when I print the first column, I get this:

```
WrappedArray(@marykatherine_q, know!, I, heard, afternoon, wondered, thing., Moscow, times)
WrappedArray(laying, bed, voice..)
WrappedArray(I'm, sooo, sad!!!, killed, Kutner, House, whyyyyyyyy)
```

when I print the second column, I get this:

```
[-0.0495405454809467,0.03403271486361821,0.011959535030958552,-0.008446224654714266,0.0014322120696306229]
[-0.06924172700382769,0.02562551060691476,0.01857258938252926,-0.0269106051127892,-0.011274430900812149]
[-0.06266747579416808,0.007715661790879334,0.047578315007472956,-0.02747830021989477,-0.015755867421188775]
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`text`' given input columns: [result, value];
```

It seems apparent that my case class has type mismatch with actual result. What should be the correct one? I want `val output` to be `DataSet[_]`.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I've modified the case class column names to be same as the word2vec output. Now I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: need an array field but got struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>;
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, it is just a problem of attribute naming. What spark is telling you is that it cannot find the attribute `text` in the dataframe `result`.

You do not say how you create the `data` object but it must have an attribute `value` since `Word2vec` manages to find it. `model.transform` simply adds a `result` column to that dataset, and turns it into a dataframe of the following type:

```
root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- vector: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = false)
 |-- result: vector (nullable = true)
```

So when you try to turn it into a dataset, spark tries to find a `text` column and throws that exception. Just rename the `value` column and it will work:

```scala
val output = result.withColumnRenamed("value", "text").as(encoder)
```

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this. I've made the changes in my code but encountered another error. Please refer to the edit.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the source code of `word2vec`, I managed to realise that the output of transform is actually not Array[Float], it is actually `Vector` (from o.a.s.ml.linalg).

It worked by changing case class as below:

```
case class vectorData(value: Array[String], vectors: Vector)
```